# Can i put code and new classes in a lot of parts of my solution automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, t4

I want to put code that i generate automatically and new classes in different parts of my solution. Ex:

I have these projects:

- Model
- DAO
- Business
- Web

When i create manually a new entity in `Model` project i want to:

- Create in `Model` project your IDAO class and IService class
- Create in `DAO` project your DAO class.
- Create in `Business` project your Service class.
- Create in `Application_Start()` method that is in `Web\global.asax` file the code that register the interfaces to your classes (Denpendency Injection).

All things automatically. So, is it possible?

Comment: don't think it's possible, honestly. You can achieve a part of that using, naturally, T4 templates, but not definitely that kind of destribution you're asking for. May be you can write your own plugin for that purpose.

Comment: There is a "kind" of plugin for this purpose, a name that would facilitate my search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I use visual studio macros.

Obs: I changed the strategy. Instead of create a T4 file (.tt), i create a common class file (.cs) with some tags that will be changed by String.Replace.

```
using System;
// place here your necessary "usings" 

namespace #namespace#
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class responsible for #entity# data access.
    /// </summary>
    public class #class# : I#class#
    {
    }
}
```

The Macro:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO

Public Module Templates
    ' Get the active class (in this case will be the entity that you have just created)
    Dim entity As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Name.Replace(".cs", "")
    Dim projects As Projects = DTE.Solution.Projects
    ' Project where are the template classes   
    Dim projectTemplates As Project = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject

    Sub CreateCRUD()

        ' Exemple of creating DAO Class
        CreateClass("NamespaceWhereAreYouProject.Repositorio\ NamespaceWhereAreYouProject.Repositorio.csproj", _
                    "DAL", _
                    " NamespaceWhereAreYouProject.Repository.DAL", _
                    "DAO" + entity, _
                    "DAOTemplate.cs")

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateClass(ByVal currentProject As String, _
                                 ByVal currentFolder As String, _
                                 ByVal currentNamespace As String, _
                                 ByVal currentClass As String, _
                                 ByVal currentTemplate As String)

        ' Loading attributes
        Dim project As Project = projects.Item(currentProject)
        Dim folder As ProjectItem = project.ProjectItems.Item(currentFolder)
        Dim currentTemplatePath As String = projectTemplates.ProjectItems.Item("Templates") _
            .ProjectItems.Item(currentTemplate).Properties.Item("FullPath").Value
        Dim newClassPath As String = folder.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value + currentClass + ".cs"

        ' Creating class
        folder.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(currentTemplatePath, currentClass + ".cs")
        Dim newText As String = File.ReadAllText(newClassPath) _
            .Replace("#class#", currentClass) _
            .Replace("#namespace#", currentNamespace) _
            .Replace("#entity#", entity)
        File.WriteAllText(newClassPath, newText)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

It always depend on the project and what you try to achieve.

I use T4 to avoid having to *maintain* redundant code. In the scenario your describe very often there are code that feels redundant and is hard to make non-redundant.

What I would do:

- Describe my model somehow (T4 code, XML or whatever you like)
- Create a T4 template that takes the model and build the Model classes
- Create a T4 template that takes the model and build the DAO classes
- Create a T4 template that takes the model and build the Business classes
- Create a T4 template that registers the classes for dependency injection

When I add a new entity to my mode file I would hit "Transform All Templates" in VS or add it to the build system. This will generate the necessary code for Model, DAO, Business and Application_Start.

If this solution is good or bad depends on the project you are working on and what you want to achieve.

Comment: How can i hit "Transform All Templates" when i add a new entity to my `Model`? Obs: I create all t4 templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this sort of stuff pretty easily using Visual Studio Macros.

THere are two places to get started:

- Search the web for VS macros that create documents, or apply other actions that you are interested in
- Look at the Tools > Macros menu. From here you can Record a temporary macro (start recording, then do an aciton such as creating a document, then stop recording). Then open the recording macro in the Macros IDE to see what code it has generated (for some actions you won't get anything, but most of the time VS is very good at generating somehting useful from your UI actions). Then you just have to stitch together the snippets of code you've recorded and it's often pretty easy to build up a macro to automate tedius tasks.